# Use a Scanner to return a String

Tags: java, string, netbeans, split, java.util.scanner

So, brand new to this site, but looks promising..

Anyways, to business, I'm working on this bit of code and I'm trying to return a string using a scanner. I've also tried using a BufferedReader, but it still returns null.

```
public String scanFile(String lineStarter) throws IOException {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String[] lineInfo = sc.nextLine().toString().split("//|");
        if(lineStarter.equalsIgnoreCase(lineInfo[0])){
            return sc.toString();
        }
    }

    //this is what keeps on returning
    return null;
}
```

The text file is formated like this:

```
starwars|cool|Actor|general|google|low
starw|cool|Actor|general|google|low
hark|dude|this|I|don't|know
```

So ya, it keeps on returning the last line that I don't want to return...

I guess, if you really want it, I call the method while opening a new file I guess

```
private void doubleClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                               
    if(evt.getClickCount()==2){

        try {
            String s = (String) jList1.getSelectedValue();
            System.out.println(s);
            new DisplayMovie(scanFile(s)).setVisible(true);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("An Error has occured");
        }
    }
}
```

I hope I explained it well enouph, any suggestions will hopefully help

Comment: Next time make sure to tag your language for more exposure to your question, and so others know what language you are working with. I've done it for you this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your split is incorrect.

```
.split("//|");
```

The forward slash is not an escape. You need backslash

```
.split("\\|");
```

With the first code, it will not split correctly, therefore you will get no matches and your method will always return null unless you pass the entire line as a string to the method